# How do I implement a basic character counter in a simple_form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, simple-form

I am using simple_form for my form, and would love to enable some basic JS character count on a text field.

My form partial looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %> 

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input_field :parent_id, as: :hidden %>

    <div class="field">
    <% if can? :manage, @post %>
            <%= f.input_field :status, label: "Status", collection: Post.statuses.keys, selected: :unconfirmed %>   
    <% end %>       
    </div>

    <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Enter Title" %>
    <%= f.input :photo %>
        <%= f.input :file %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
        <div class="report-submit">
            <%= f.button :submit %>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: where is big text field?

Comment: @RSB `f.input :body`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign an `id` to the text field, then add a `span` beside it where you will show the counter, assign an `id` to the span as well.

```
<%= f.input :body, id: "body-field" %>
<span id="body-count">0 characters</span>
```

In Javascript add this code

```
$("#body-field").on("keyup", function(){
    length = $(this).val().length;
    $("#body-count").html(length);
});
```

I have created a fiddle to show how it works, click here http://jsfiddle.net/L99c30qh/

Comment: One more request - how do I convert this to a word counter rather than just a character counter? Is that simple?